# Change ranges for ALL conditional formatting rules?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a few sheets with easily 20+ conditional formatting rules.

Apparently, Sheets doesn't like moving cells around, because it just completely messes up the ranges defined in all of the conditional formatting rules. Something... "normal" turns into `A1:E355,F1:F16,G1:G19,H1:P355,F19,F21:G24,F33:G355`.

Is there a way to change all the CF ranges back to, for example, `A:AA` without having to go through each and every one "by hand" and pasting the normal range definition in there?

Comment: unfortunately no. you will need to play with it manually

Comment: @player0 Bummer... I was nearly sure it would be possible, since they allow you to define and edit rules using their "macro" / script feature.

Comment: @DeBedenHasen Have you considered using Google Apps Script for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a super simple answer (I didn't know Apps Script that well when I asked this question)...

```js
function changeRanges()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rules = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();

  var entireSheet = [sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns())];

  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
  {
    rules[i] = rules[i].copy().setRanges(entireSheet).build();
  }
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Works universally, but it's obviously dangerous as it'll thoroughly mess up color scales or similar.